# Download source code from app_engine now that appcfg is gone?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm, google-cloud-platform

We have hit an issue where our dependencies weren't locked and now we think a sub-dependency has been changed, causing issues in our application.  I want to download the node_modules from app_engine for the functioning deployed code, but I have hit a number of issues:

1. The old way of doing this, appcfg, is deprecated and the download_app functionality is entirely gone.
2. The source tool in app engine's versions doesn't let you download the code--only see the raw text.  The issue with that is there are hundreds, if not thousands, of packages installed so this is not a practical solution to do manually.

The best solution I can think of here is to scrape the page and download everything, but I'm hoping there is a better solution.

Comment: If you ever pushed your code to the Cloud Repository, you can run `$ gcloud source repos clone <Project name> --project=<Project ID>` to clone it to a local repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifact for each deployed build is stored in GCS, go into [GCS Browser](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser), find a bucket which has `artifacts` in its name, and there are all your previous builds.

Comment: This looks like it's container images, not the code that was uploaded to it.  Maybe I don't know enough about the container images, are you able to get into the image and get the code from that?  I'm not actually looking to retrieve the code, more so the sub-versions of all of the packages being used in there.

Comment: it's `.tar.gz` file, afaik each file stands on its own. Download it, rename it to `<file>.tar.gz`, extract and there is your code.

Comment: Perhaps we're deploying in slightly different ways.  It appears everything I have in there is an image for a container.  I tried downloading it and untarring it after renaming it like you suggested, and it isn't a compatible file type.  It could be the app engine deployment type (flex vs standard).  I'm going to accept your answer, since this got most of the way here.  We ended up solving the technical problem and didn't need to go through this approach.